# How can I prevent a thread from decrementing a semaphore until another thread is ready?

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I'm doing a `sem_post()` inside a loop but it does not appear to increase the target semaphore's value.  Here's the code:

```
void* producerFunc(void* arg)
{
    int x, d, i, semValue, semTaken;

    sem_getvalue(&sem_posTaken, &semTaken);
    sem_getvalue(&sem_posAvaliable, &semValue);
    while(n_insertions < N_PRODUCTS)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem_posAvaliable);    //Verifica se tem espaço vazio no buffer
        sem_getvalue(&sem_posAvaliable, &semValue);
        x = produce_item();
        sem_wait(&db);
        insert_buffer(x);
        sem_post(&db);

        printf("n_insertions: %d\n", n_insertions);
        if(n_insertions % 5 == 0){
            sem_getvalue(&sem_posTaken, &semValue);
            for(i=0; i< Buffer_Size; i++)
            {
                sem_getvalue(&sem_posTaken, &semTaken);
                printf("VOU DAR POST %d\n", semTaken);
                sem_post(&sem_posTaken);   //Sinaliza para o consumidor que já tem item no buffer
                sem_getvalue(&sem_posTaken, &semTaken);
                printf("DEI POST %d\n", semTaken);
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

After initially posting the question I traced down the problem to the behavior of another thread running this code:

```
void* consumerFunc(void* arg)
{
    int d;
    struct sConsumer* cons = (struct sConsumer*) arg;
    while(n_consumed < N_PRODUCTS)
    {
        n_consumed++;
        sem_wait(&sem_posTaken); //Verifica se já tem item dentro do Buffer_Size
        sem_wait(&mutex);       //Garante acesso exclusivo
        consumers++;
        if(consumers == 1)
            sem_wait(&db);
        remove_buffer(cons->id);
        sem_getvalue(&sem_posTaken, &d);
        printf("Taken: %d\n", d);
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&sem_posAvaliable);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        consumers--;
        if(consumers == 0)
            sem_post(&db);
        sem_post(&mutex);

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
```

I intend for the thread running `ProducerFunc` to fill the whole buffer and then increment the `sem_postaken` semaphore to a value corresponding to the number of occupied slots.  Upon the producer's `sem_post()`, however, the consumer, which was blocked waiting on that semaphore, proceeds, decrementing the semaphore and looping around to wait again.  This explains why the producer never sees a value greater than zero when it performs a `sem_getvalue()`.

How can I prevent the consumer from decrementing the semaphore until the producer has performed all the increments it intends to do?

Comment: Please show us [an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and check for errors.  Perhaps [`sem_getvalue`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_getvalue.html) is returning ENOSYS (because you're on, e.g., OS X) or EINVAL (because the semaphore is not initialized correctly or is otherwise corrupted).

Comment: Your code works for me when I put a complete program around it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Any idea what could be causing this problem ??

Comment: Play, @pilcrow has already given you some likely suggestions.  Have you checked them?

Comment: @JohnBollinger just did

Comment: I am not sure your question makes sense. You have a thread waiting on a semaphore, and you seem to be upset when that semaphore becomes available. But why?

Comment: Another comment: You seem to be using sem_getvalue for reasons other than debugging and statistics ... you can't do that. A semaphore is an atomic integer, essentially. By the time your code has read its value with sem_getvalue, it could have been incremented or decremented an arbitrary number of times by other threads. And if you have protected it with a mutex lock, then just use an ordinary integer. If you are trying to do lock-free programming you'll need a lot more than semaphores, this code here is not even close.

Comment: @ZanLynx  Thanks. yeah, just for debugging. Because it was my goal, now I need to change it without touching ConsumerFunc. I need to fill the whole buffer and empty it entirely before pass the processor to the other...

Comment: The only way to change the behavior without changing `ConsumerFunc()` is to defer starting the thread in which `ConsumerFunc()` runs until after `ProducerFunc()` has filled the buffer.  And of course that only works for the first fill.  One thread cannot unilaterally force another thread to cooperate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm trying to re-do the `ConsumerFunc()` then apply it to the previous goal (same thing but no need to consume and fill the whole buff at each interation).

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of waiting on a semaphore is that the thread doing so can proceed immediately as soon as the semaphore's value is greater than zero.  Therefore, if you don't want the consumer to proceed immediately when the producer posts to your semaphore, then you must ensure that the consumer is not waiting on that semaphore at that time.

I suspect that you are trying to use semaphores in a way that they are not designed to support.  The *only* information that a semaphore's value should be interpreted to convey is the number of times that semaphore can be decremented before the next increment without blocking.  It is generally a bad idea to try to make any further interpretation of that data.  Moreover, that data must be considered stale as soon as it is returned.  Use shared variables (accessed with appropriate synchronization) to convey any other needed data.

With that said, you do have a second semaphore that you name "mutex".  The details of what you're doing with it look pretty fishy, but if you really want to prevent the consumer from proceeding until the producer is ready, and the producer's readiness is not adequately conveyed by the `sem_posTaken` semaphore, then the immediately apparent solution is to use a separate semaphore to do so -- maybe `mutex`.